# Acer Swidt 3 AMD Ryzen 5/Amd Radeon Grpahics External Monitor "No Signal"

Tags: hdmi, monitor

I'm stumped, I have searched up and down this forum and others with solutions for others and cannot figure out a solution.

For reference I am not the most skilled Ubuntu user but am using it for class. A previous class used 20.04 and I had no issues with the same monitor and HDMI cord, different class needed 18.04 and now the monitor displays "No Signal" while plugged in.

This computer has AMD Radeon graphics card as well.

Research:

- [HDMI port not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078539/hdmi-port-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [HDMI not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121132/hdmi-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [External HDMI monitor detected but no signal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304548/external-hdmi-monitor-detected-but-no-signal)

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include more detailed hardware specifications as well as the exact kernel you are running? Depending on the hardware, 18.04 may not be properly compatible.

Comment: You may have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1081494). Are you sure you need 18.04? Depending on what you're doing, using 20.04 and just running 18.04 in Docker might work for you.

Comment: Some time ago I could solve such problem only by updating to 18.10. Advice from @cocomac seems to be correct.